# Window is not defined in Angular

Tags: angular, window, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, serve

I am trying to implement Server side rendering in my Angular project using angular universal, for that I referred to the documentation but am quite not able to proceed further as on executing `npm run dev:ssr` I am getting bundles generated but process fails complete execution due to an error which is

```
D:\CMS_clone1\CMS\CMSBIZ_admin_interface\dist\angular11-sample-app\server\main.js:100191
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || {};
^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
   at Module.9vUh (D:\CMS_clone1\CMS\CMSBIZ_admin_interface\dist\angular11-sample-app\server\main.js:100191:1)
   at __webpack_require__ (D:\CMS_clone1\CMS\CMSBIZ_admin_interface\dist\angular11-sample-app\server\main.js:26:30)
   at Module.vY5A (D:\CMS_clone1\CMS\CMSBIZ_admin_interface\dist\angular11-sample-app\server\main.js:382815:78)
   at __webpack_require__ (D:\CMS_clone1\CMS\CMSBIZ_admin_interface\dist\angular11-sample-app\server\main.js:26:30)
   at Module.ZAI4 (D:\CMS_clone1\CMS\CMSBIZ_admin_interface\dist\angular11-sample-app\server\main.js:236347:78)
   at __webpack_require__ (D:\CMS_clone1\CMS\CMSBIZ_admin_interface\dist\angular11-sample-app\server\main.js:26:30)
   at Module.24aS (D:\CMS_clone1\CMS\CMSBIZ_admin_interface\dist\angular11-sample-app\server\main.js:51247:69)
   at __webpack_require__ (D:\CMS_clone1\CMS\CMSBIZ_admin_interface\dist\angular11-sample-app\server\main.js:26:30)
   at Module.K011 (D:\CMS_clone1\CMS\CMSBIZ_admin_interface\dist\angular11-sample-app\server\main.js:174790:80)
   at __webpack_require__ (D:\CMS_clone1\CMS\CMSBIZ_admin_interface\dist\angular11-sample-app\server\main.js:26:30)

A server error has occurred.
node exited with 1 code.
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:59092
```

I am stuck at this for a couple of days now, I tried a few suggestions related to domino, mockBrowser but neither seemed to help, If anyone can possibly help me out to resolve this issue of mine it would be a lot helpful. Thanking in advance.

Comment: Wherever you call the `window` object, you should just check it with `if (typeof window !== 'undefined') { }`

Comment: Try adding domino

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? @Shivam 

I have the exact same issue.

Comment: Hi @Rahul I tried checking up with a condition based on typeof window as suggested but wasn't quite able to find the needed resolution, as it landed me up with some other set of errors. conclusively: I got rid of this error by framing a condition check wherever I was using window.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a few weeks back. SSR doesn't have any idea as to what a window or document is, so I added the following into server.ts:

```js
const MockBrowser = require('mock-browser').mocks.MockBrowser;
const mock = new MockBrowser();
global['window'] = mock.getWindow();

// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
bootstrap: AppServerModule,
}));
```

Comment: Hi, as I forementioned I already tried out mockBrowser but that didn't quite seemed to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my server.ts file, I have added all the code, basically create window is giving the error most of the time. Once am able to compile the code. Then am able to access the window and local storage.

```html
import 'localstorage-polyfill'
import { existsSync } from 'fs'
import { join } from 'path'

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node'
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine'
import express from 'express'

import { createWindow } from 'domino'
const indexHtml = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/nbinar/browser/index2.html')
const win = createWindow(indexHtml)

// Polyfills
;(global as any).window = win
;(global as any).document = win.document
;(global as any).navigator = win.navigator

// needs to be after window definition
import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server'

import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common'

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  global['localStorage'] = localStorage
  const server = express()
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/notus-angular/browser')
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html'))
    ? 'index.original.html'
    : 'index'

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', (_, options: { req: any }, callback) => {
    const engine = ngExpressEngine({
      bootstrap: AppServerModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: 'request', useFactory: () => options.req as any, deps: [] }
      ]
    })
    engine(_, options, callback)
  })

  server.set('view engine', 'html')
  server.set('views', distFolder)

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get(
    '*.*',
    express.static(distFolder, {
      maxAge: '1y'
    })
  )

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, {
      req,
      providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }]
    })
  })

  return server
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app()
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main
const moduleFilename = (mainModule && mainModule.filename) || ''
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run()
}

export * from './src/main.server'
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a component called `bs-stepper` which needs window at load time, I try the @Fizz-Pop-Bang solution but it still have the problem because the main problem is the order how webpack loads the components, so I have to do a module import instead a require import, so I write the following workaround.

File `src/browser-polyfill.ts`

```js
const MockBrowser = require('mock-browser').mocks.MockBrowser;
const browser = new MockBrowser();

global['window'] = browser.getWindow();
global['document'] = browser.getDocument();
```

File `server.ts`

```
// at the top of the imports/file
import './src/browser-polyfill';
```